# Which synchronization primitive should I employ here?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, race-condition

```c
while(1) {
     char message_buffer[SIZE];
     ssize_t message_length = mq_receive(mq_identifier, message_buffer, _mqueue_max_msg_size NULL);

     if(message_len == -1) { /* error handling... */}

     pthread_t pt1;
     int ret = pthread_create(&pt1, NULL, handle_message, message_buffer);
     if(ret) { /* error handling ... */}
}

void * handle_message (void * message) {
    puts((char *) message);
    return NULL;
}
```

The above example is not an MRE but it is extremely simple:

I've got a main thread with a loop that constantly consumes messages from a message queue. Once a new message is received, it is stored in the local `message_buffer` buffer. Then, a new thread is spawned to "take care" of said new message, and thus the message buffer's address is passed into `handle_message`, which the new thread subsequently executes.

---

## The problem

Often, 2 threads will print the same message, even though I can verify with a 100% certainty that the messages in the queue were not the same.

---

I am not completely certain, but I think I understand why this is happening:

say that I push 2 different messages to the mqueue and only then I begin consuming them.

In the first iteration of the `while` loop, the message will get consumed from the queue and saved to `message_buffer`. A new thread will get spawned and the address of `message_length` passed to it. But that thread may not be fast enough to print the buffer's contents to the stream *before* the next message gets consumed (on the next iteration of the loop), and the contents of `message_buffer` subsequently overridden. Thus the first and second thread now print the same value.

---

My question is: what is the most efficient way to solve this? I'm pretty new to parallel programming and threading/pthreads and I'm pretty overwhelmed by the different synchronization primitives.

## Mutex trouble

```c
static pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

while(1) {
     char message_buffer[SIZE];
     pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
     ssize_t message_length = mq_receive(mq_identifier, message_buffer, _mqueue_max_msg_size NULL);
     pthred_mutex_unlock(&m);

     if(message_len == -1) { /* error handling... */}

     pthread_t pt1;
     int ret = pthread_create(&pt1, NULL, handle_message, message_buffer);
     if(ret) { /* error handling ... */}
}

void * handle_message (void * message) {
    char own_buffer[SIZE];
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    strncpy(own_buffer, (char *) message, SIZE);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
    puts(own_buffer);
    return NULL;
}
```

I don't think my current mutex implementation is right as the threads are still receiving duplicate messages. The main thread can lock the mutex, consume a message into the buffer, unlock the mutex, spawn a thread, but that thread still may hang  and the main one could just rewrite the buffer again (as the buffer mutex was never locked by the new thread), effectively making my current mutex implementation useless? How do I overcome this?

Comment: Your assessment is correct. But the structure of your program is a bit flawed. If you only have one buffer what is the point of spawning a thread to consume it. There is no parallelisation benefits because with a single buffer the main thread and all other threads would need to wait for the message to be consumed before a new message can be written into the buffer. Certainly you could protect the buffer with a mutex but what would be the point of that? It would be functionally correct in that only one thread will ever access the buffer but would have no concurrency benefits.

Comment: @kaylum This is a watered-down version of the actual code: in it, each thread reads the buffer and saves its own copy of it so that it can continue to work on it while other threads parallelly do the same with their own messages. I want to protect the message buffer for as long as it takes for the thread to create its own copy of it, but I'm wondering what 's the best way to do that.

Comment: In that case you can use a mutex. See [pthread_muex_lock](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock). Depending on your real application you may find that contention for the buffer may become a bottle neck. And for high performance applications you would aim to minimise copying of buffers.

Comment: @kaylum Thank you, I'll try to implement a mutex. By "contention for the buffer", do you mean that a bottleneck will occur if messages come in quicker than each thread can fire up, create a copy, and unlock the mutex? Creating a copy is done with a simple `strncpy` so I don't think that part will be an issue, but I'm not too versed in the real-world cost of spawning threads and unlocking mutexes, so I can't judge on that.

Comment: Yes that's mostly what I mean by contention. In a small application with small data it may be fine. But imagine if there are high frequency and/or large messages. Common case is packet handling - there could be a million packets per second. If all packets have to use the same buffer you can easily see that there is no way the system could handle even a fraction of the max number of packets.

Comment: @kaylum Thank you. I seem to have encountered a roadblock while attempting to implement the mutex though, please see my edit in the original post.

Comment: in general, each thread will execute outside of your control.  Therefore, after this statement: `ssize_t message_length = mq_receive(mq_identifier, message_buffer, _mqueue_max_msg_size NULL);`  call `malloc()` for the value in `message_length` then copy the message into that 'malloc'd area, then pass that 'malloc'd area in the call to `pthread_create()`  Note: the thread function needs to call `free()` on the passed parameter.

Comment: @user3629249 I understand that that's a possibility, but is it not possible to achieve the desired result using synchronization?

Comment: Somewhere, in the main thread, need to call `pthread_join()` for each thread created, before the program exits.  which means each call to `pthread_create()` sets a thread ID, so there needs to be an array of those `thread ID`s kept for the calls to `pthread_join()`.  Generally, a thread should exit via a call to `pthread_exit()`

Comment: The only synchronization needed is that each thread gets a pointer to a unique buffer

Comment: @user3629249 `pthread_create(3)` says: "The new thread terminates in one of the following ways: ... ... ... * It  returns from start_routine().  This is equivalent to calling pthread_exit(3) with the value supplied in the return statement."

Comment: Instead of calling `mq_receive` then create a thread, why not do it the other way around: Create threads that call `mq_receive`. The whole problem goes away. (You can see it in practice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60237695/589924). It uses a custom queue module, but the concept is the same.)

Comment: @ikegami I'd thought of that but say that I initially spawn 3 threads and they all poll for messages and do their thing - how would I know when to (from the main thread) increase the number of threads when it becomes necessary?

Comment: What is the point of conveying the message to another thread that has to be created and such when you have a perfectly good thread that could process the message? If you care about performance, why go through the trouble of creating new threads and passing work from thread to thread rather than re-using threads and keeping threads working as long as possible?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz "processing messages" in this question was just an analogy, the actual function deals with pipes and other blocking calls - after a bit of research it seems that what you're suggesting has a name - "thread pool", but as I'd mentioned in a previous comment, how would I know when to increase the number of threads in the pool?

Comment: @bool3max, Re "*I'd thought of that but ...*", Keep track of how many of the threads are idle (blocked waiting for `mq_receive`) and how many are busy (processing a message). Before a thread would call `mq_receive`, it checks how many threads are idle and exits rather than calling `mq_receive` if there are too many idle threads. After a call to `mq_receive` returns, the thread check if there are enough idle threads and spawns more if there aren't.

Comment: ...Of course, that accepts your assumption that there's a benefit to adjusting the thread pool size. Is there?

Comment: @bool3max You use a thread pool that autotunes or just compute the number of threads. It's almost certainly not something you need to worry about any time soon and can just get away with creating a few extra threads.

Comment: regarding *but is it not possible to achieve the desired result using synchronization?*  There is no need for any synchronization.  Applying synchronization techniques will only slow down the handling of the incoming messages.  Such slowing down of the message handling is very likely to result in a backup of the message queue and possible missed messages.  The seuqence of `malloc()`  `memcpy()` `pthread_create()` `free()` does not stop/pace the handling of incoming messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you end the loop that contains `message_buffer` before guaranteeing that the thread has finished with that memory.

```
while (1) {
    char message_buffer[SIZE];
    ssize_t message_length = mq_receive(...);
    if (message_len == -1) { /* error handling */ }

    pthread_t pt1;
    int ret = pthread_create(&pt1, NULL, handle_message, message_buffer);
    if (ret) { /* error handling */ }

    /****** Can't go beyond here until thread is done with message_buffer. ******/
}

void * handle_message (void * message) {
    char own_buffer[SIZE];
    strncpy(own_buffer, (char *) message, SIZE);

    /******* Only now can the caller loop back. ******/

    puts(own_buffer);
    return NULL;
}
```

You could use a semaphore or similar.

```
static pthread_mutex_t mutex  = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t  cond   = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
static int             copied = 0;

while (1) {
    char message_buffer[SIZE];
    ssize_t message_length = mq_receive(...);
    if (message_len == -1) { /* error handling */ }

    pthread_t pt1;
    int ret = pthread_create(&pt1, NULL, handle_message, message_buffer);
    if (ret) { /* error handling */ }

    // Wait until threads is done with message_buffer.
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while (!copied) pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
    copied = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void * handle_message (void * message) {
    char own_buffer[SIZE];
    strncpy(own_buffer, (char *) message, SIZE);

    // Done with caller's buffer.
    // Signal caller to continue.
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    copied = 1;
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    puts(own_buffer);
    return NULL;
}
```

(The added chunks effectively perform semaphore operations. See the last snippet of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60225205/589924) for a more generic implementation.)

But there's a simpler solution: Make the copy before creating the thread.

```
while (1) {
    char message_buffer[SIZE];
    ssize_t message_length = mq_receive(...);
    if (message_len == -1) { /* error handling */ }

    pthread_t pt1;
    int ret = pthread_create(&pt1, NULL, handle_message, strdup(message_buffer));
    if (ret) { /* error handling */ }
}

void * handle_message (void * message) {
    char * own_buffer = message;
    puts(own_buffer);
    free(own_buffer);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It will be interesting to benchmark these 2 approaches against a thread-pool based one if I ever get around to doing it.

Comment: There's a flaw in this: if `pthread_create` fails, you lose the pointer to `strdup(message_buffer)`, so unless `/* error handling */` does something drastic like `exit(1)`, you have a memory leak.

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica, Error handling was intentionally omitted for the sake of brevity. The approach can be used while still avoiding a memory leak

Comment: How? You allocated memory but don't have a pointer to it anymore. You'd need to add code before the call to `pthread_create` to save it; just adding code to `/* error handling */` would be insufficient.

Comment: By storing the pointer in a variable, and passing that variable to `free` when `pthread_create` fails.

Comment: Well yes, but my point was that necessitates adding code outside of just where `/* error handling */` is.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I know. And I said I did that intentionally.

Comment: Okay, I see the confusion now. When you said "Error handling was intentionally omitted",  I took it to mean that all of the omitted code would be where you marked `/* error handling */`, but it's now clear that that's not what you meant.